# Management, manager and manage

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

What's the correct to name a process that controls my book collection?

For example: This software works like a ___________

1. Books management
2. Books manager
3. Books' manage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is correct. That is *a manager that manages your books*.